# Super Mario Maker startup

Tags: super-mario-maker

My son is getting Super Mario Maker for Christmas.  He has plenty of experience with the Mario side-scrollers.  Will he be able to put the disc in and go, or does the game require any initial setup?  I know that you can download levels from other players, but does it also come with some "factory-installed" levels?

Comment: If you have questions along the way don't hesitate to ask me again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No initial set-up is actually required, once you put the disc in you have 3 choices.

1. Go on "adventure mode" which makes you play random levels depending on the difficulty you pick. This is found by clicking on *100 Mario Challenge*. (Click play)
2. Start creating a level with the items you get by default. This can be found by clicking *make*, and not *play*.
3. Play levels online. Which can be found by clicking on *Courses*. (Click play)

Comment: No mention of the 10 Mario Challenge, which is solely levels made by Nintendo?

Answer (score 4):

[Note that there have been some free updates to *Super Mario Maker* since it's launch](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15184), which will require downloading and installing, and you might be unable to use the online modes until you do so. This should not prevent you from playing the game offline, however.

In terms of offline content, there is of course the level editor, which the game gives a tutorial on the first time you play. Additionally, there is the *10 Mario Challenge*, in which you play through 8 courses created by Nintendo designers. There are a few dozen such courses, and after completing a course it becomes available to play around with in the level editor.

Comment: The updates happen automatically, this is not initial set-up therefore it was not very useful to point out. All updates needed for the game take no more than 20 minutes.